# Must I have seen a type of flower with my own eyes to use the Staff of Flowers to cause that type of flower to sprout?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I've said this before, but the [*staff of flowers*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-flowers) (XGtE, p. 139) is a surprisingly useful item for its level.

Does the *staff of flowers* require me to **know** a flower, or just know **of** a flower, to cause that flower to sprout?
Specifically, I want to know exactly how much knowledge of a flower is reasonable to grow it. Does one need to know the name? How it looks? Where it grows? How it can be used? All of the above?

Does one even need to know that something is a flower to make it grow? If a character has never seen Sugar Cane and hears the name, and they want to know if it's a flower or not, can they grow it? What if they know everything else about the plant except that it's a flower, and they want to confirm that it is one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No

Spells only do what they say they do. Wild Shape for example, says that you can only transform into a creature you have seen before. Staff of Flowers has no such wording.

**But what I want to know is does the staff require me to know a flower, or just know of a flower?**

You have to choose the flower, so you should at least know of it.

**Specifically I want to know exactly how much knowledge of a flower is reasonable to grow it. Does one need to know the name? How it looks? Where it grows? How it can be used? All of the above?**

The name or having a mental sense of "that one" is enough. Regardless if your PC is thinking "that white flower that grows by my house", you need to communicate that to your DM.

**Does one even need to know it's a flower to make it grow? If a character has never seen Sugar Cane and hears the name and they want to know if it's a flower or not, can they grow it? What if they know everything else about the plant except that it's a flower and they want to confirm it?**

Sugar cane isn't a valid choice. Usually when you try to make an invalid choice in the game, the DM will tell you "pick something else".